# iBus transmission and read it in Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I am using an Arduino Uno and I want to transmit data from FSi6 to FS-iA6B and read received data in an Arduino. After searching, I found the below link which is **iBUStelemetry**.

[iBustelemetry](https://github.com/Hrastovc/iBUStelemetry)

I am not able to make out how to get the data from this library and print it on the serial monitor.

I have hooked up receiver ground and power pins to ground and power pins of Arduino. Signal from the receiver is connected to D2.

The author has included an example, but I am not much clear how data is read and printed on the serial monitor.

Can someone please help by telling how do I read data from receiver using this library?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the code should look like this.

```
#include <iBUStelemetry.h>
iBUStelemetry telemetry(4);
byte i;

void setup(){
 Serial.begin(115200); 
 telemetry.begin(115200);
 telemetry.addSensor(2);
}

void loop(){
 telemetry.setSensorMeasurement(1, i++);
 delay(1000);
 Serial.println(telemetry);
 //or
 Serial.println(telemetry.setSensorMeasurement(1, i++));
}
```

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/print/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The output should be value of each individual channels from the RC remote. This does not give any active results. Expected code should be something like:

`for (i = 0; i < noOfCh; i++){
 chvals[i] = IBus.readChannel(i);
}`

Can you kindly check and revert?